# saving excel files as a pdf

Tags: excel, automation

I am looking for the best solution to do the following:

I have around 640 Excel files each with about 9 - 12 sheets in them. I would like to save each sheet as a PDF. Currently, the process is done manually.  Select sheet -> File -> Save as -> pdf -> navigate through a million folders. As you can see this is very time consuming and inefficient.

I know how to program in C# however I don't have visual studio on my machine. However if the best way to do this is VS then maybe I can get the IT team to install VS if they have a license for me.

The only tools available to me are Excel (not even Access is available). So I will be mainly looking for VBA code. If this means opening up each file to paste VBA code in, it will still be quicker then saving each sheet as PDF.

Comment: how could we help you?... by the way, you don't need to place vba code to each of the file you want to save as PDF but you will need to open each file to save it as VBA...

Comment: Record a macro while processing a single file: that should give you a good starting point.

Comment: @KazJaw No, a single VBA macro can open .xls workbooks and save them as PDF. No need to convert them all to .xlsm

Comment: @Jack, I don't get you. I didn't say anything about converting to .xlsm... Oh, now I see what I've written above, I meant 'save it as PDF' not 'save it as VBA'... you are a bit right....

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish your goal using PowerShell

**ExportTo-ExcelPDF.ps1**

```
$path = "c:\fso" 
$xlFixedFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type] 
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.xls, *.xlsx -recurse 
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$objExcel.visible = $false 
foreach($wb in $excelFiles) 
{ 
 $filepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($wb.BaseName + ".pdf") 
 $workbook = $objExcel.workbooks.open($wb.fullname, 3) 
 $workbook.Saved = $true 
"saving $filepath" 
 $workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath) 
 $objExcel.Workbooks.close() 
} 
$objExcel.Quit()
```

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/06/save-a-microsoft-excel-workbook-as-a-pdf-file-by-using-powershell.aspx

It is also fairly straightforward to use the same COM API in C#, which you can accomplish with the free Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Comment: Can powershell be installed on Win XP? Or is there a CMD alternative

Comment: I just tested this, it works fine HOWEVER it saves all the sheets in one pdf. I would like to save each sheet as a separate pdf. So for each excel file with 9 - 12 sheets, I should get 9 - 12 pdfs back.

Comment: You could setup an inner loop, and call ExportAsFixedFormat once per sheet on each workbook with the parameters *From* and *To* specifying the page range desired.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238907(v=office.12).aspx